# Generate a cookie when user closes a webform block

Tags: blocks, webforms, cookies

I have been tasked with having to setup a cookie that records when an anonymous user closes a newsletter signup webform block so that it no longer appears when reloading the current page or navigating to another page on a website.

Can anyone please advise if there is module that performs this function?

Or can someone please point me in the right direction in terms of the correct code snippet I can use to make this work?

Many thanks!

Comment: What you meen by "user closes a newsletter signup webform block" ?.Solution is simple as: create a simple event on "user closes webform click" check whatever your anonymous and set cookie with `php setcookie` function. And check whatever  your cookie is already defined, then dont show webform on your node.tpl.php. If you want to find a solution, post some more information, or code.

Comment: Hi Neok. The webform block has a close function on the front end, so when they click the "X" it hides the form. I need to set a cookie that captures that event of the user closing the form and then saves it as a user session that keeps the form hidden while the user is navigating around the website.

Comment: Still researching

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a custom module and add javascript user identificator on your page with web form(to find out user anonymous or not)
[Here is example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182674/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-in-a-drupal-site-via-javascript)

Next use [jquery library](https://jquery.com/) and do the next thing:

```
// its just an example you need to put your #id or .class
$("#subform_close").on('click', function() {
      if(Drupal.settings.user_js_uid == 0)
           {
              // set cookie for whatever you want
              $.cookie("dont_show_web_form", 1, { expires : 1 });
          }
})
```

and in your php code 
check for that cookie

```
$_COOKIE["dont_show_web_form"]
```

and hide your webform.

Comment: Its not a full answer, I showed the direction in which to look.